# Append query to specific query strings in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I'm trying to write a `RewriteRule` in my `.htaccess` file to add `"&group=core.js"` to all the strings that end in `".js?ver=*"`

I tried to mess around with the parameters but I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm looking to convert all of the links that look like this:

`www.website.com/js/scripts.js?ver=4.9.6`

to something that look like this:

`www.website.com/js/scripts.js?ver=4.9.6&group=core.js`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be working:

```
RewriteRule    ^(.*\.js\?ver=[\.0-9]+)$    $1&group=core.js
```

It can be improved in terms of what version numbers are allowed, but it’s a good starting point.

You can test the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/jPvTax/1